# No list returned while retrieving scores from Scoreloop server

Tags: android, scoreloop

I am trying to retrieve score of the device user from the Scoreloop server. It's an AndEngine game. I tried the following:

```
observer = new RequestControllerObserver() {
        @Override
        public void requestControllerDidFail(RequestController arg0,
                Exception arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void requestControllerDidReceiveResponse(
                RequestController requestController) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myScoresController = (ScoresController) requestController;
            myScoresController.setSearchList(SearchList
                    .getGlobalScoreSearchList());
            myScoresController.setMode(mode);
            myScoresController.setRangeLength(20);
            myScoresController.loadRangeForUser(Session.getCurrentSession()
                    .getUser());
            Log.i("score", "" + myScoresController.getScores().get(0).getResult());
            // List<Score> retrievedScores = myScoresController.getScores();
        }
```

The Log.i() is not even showed up. I also tried this:

```
observer = new RequestControllerObserver() {

        @Override
        public void requestControllerDidFail(RequestController arg0,
                Exception arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void requestControllerDidReceiveResponse(
                RequestController requestController) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
            myScoresController = new ScoresController(observer);
            myScoresController.setSearchList(SearchList
                    .getGlobalScoreSearchList());
            myScoresController.setMode(mode);
            myScoresController.setRangeLength(20);
            myScoresController.loadRangeForUser(Session.getCurrentSession()
                    .getUser());
            Log.i("score", "" + myScoresController.getScores().get(0).getResult());
            // List<Score> retrievedScores = myScoresController.getScores();
```

I am trying to get the first element of the list and then the score result. But there is no list coming up. The error shown as:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:102)
```

But I didn't try both of the above together. There certainly is a mistake But I don't see it.

**Edit:**

The whole class where I am using it is as follows:

```
public class ScoreLoopUpdater implements Runnable {
private double score;
private int mode;
private RequestControllerObserver observer;
private ScoresController myScoresController = null;

public ScoreLoopUpdater(double _score, int _mode) {
    this.score = _score;
    this.mode = _mode;
}

public void run() {
    getGlobalHighscore();
    ScoreloopManagerSingleton.get().onGamePlayEnded(
            score, mode);
}

private void getGlobalHighscore() {
        //the above codes including observer go inside here.
    }
```

I am calling from a scene using this:

```
ScoreLoopUpdater scoreLoopUpdater = new ScoreLoopUpdater(theScore, theMode);
activity.runOnUiThread(scoreLoopUpdater);
```

Comment: is `SearchList.getGlobalScoreSearchList()` contains any data?

Comment: I not sure what you are talking about but there is a score submitted into the server. The global leaderboard has only one score for one mode and I am accessing that mode.

Comment: can you please validate the data return by the following method `SearchList.getGlobalScoreSearchList()`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any other way to validate this. But most likely this isn't also returning any list.

Comment: `if(SearchList.getGlobalScoreSearchList() == null){ Log.d(TAG, "GlobalScoreSearchList is Null"); }` you can check this way. If null then do what you want, else perform the operation.

Comment: No, it's not returning null.

Comment: Then error is in your `myScoresController.getScores()`, this return `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Besause you never set the value to myScoresController.setScores(). Can you check it.

Comment: No, I didn't. Where to setScores() and why? I need to getScores from the server only, isn't it?.

Comment: If you haven't set the value, how you can get the value. if it is set by the server then change the code there to set the value.

Comment: It's confusing. I submitted scores using this: ScoreloopManagerSingleton.get().onGamePlayEnded(score, mode); Now the score is in the server and it is actually. But this is a separate thing. Now I want to get the score from the server. Do I still have to use setScores(). If so then where? Please recheck the edited question and tell me where to setScores.

Comment: And now I checked, there is no method called setScores() in myScoresController.

Comment: You server setting the value using`ScoreLoopUpdater(_score, _int)` method, are you passing the value for it?

Comment: Yes, I certainly do, and yes, the server has the value. Before trying to retrieve the score I tried to submit the score first and that's fine. I can see the data and it is there.

Comment: So, when you are accessing the data, you are not accessing the data from the same instance. Thus you are accessing the data from some other instance, thus you got the ArrayIndexOutofBound exception

Comment: For example, if I start the application and submitted the score and then closed the app and restart again. But now, I just want to get the score from online server where I submitted before. Isn't it possible?

Comment: yes possiable. How/ The way you getting the value is important, problem is there.

Comment: This is how I am calling it: ScoreLoopUpdater scoreLoopUpdater = new ScoreLoopUpdater(score, mode); activity.runOnUiThread(scoreLoopUpdater);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38333/discussion-between-nafis-abdullah-khan-and-yup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After gesturing with some examples I've finally come up with the proper way:

```
private void getGlobalHighscore() {
    observer = new RequestControllerObserver() {

        @Override
        public void requestControllerDidFail(RequestController arg0,
                Exception arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void requestControllerDidReceiveResponse(
                RequestController requestController) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ScoresController myScoresController = (ScoresController) requestController;
            Log.i("score", "" + myScoresController.getScores().get(0).getResult());
            // List<Score> retrievedScores = myScoresController.getScores();
        }

    };
    ScoresController myScoresController = new ScoresController(observer);
    myScoresController.setSearchList(SearchList
            .getGlobalScoreSearchList());
    myScoresController.setMode(mode);
    myScoresController.setRangeLength(20);
    myScoresController.loadRangeForUser(Session.getCurrentSession()
            .getUser());
}
```

Only getScores() should be called inside requestControllerDidReceiveResponse function, which means getting the scores after receiving the response.